# How can I solve $\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

This is what I could come up with:

$\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=0$

$\left(\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2=0^2$

$\dfrac{4x^2}{1-x^2}=0$

I can't go forward from this point because of that **stupid 0**! 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If a fraction is zero, then the numerator must be zero.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan ... provided the denominator not equals zero simultaneously.

Comment: Hi @Naveen! $\color{blue}{\large{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}}$ Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$) $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$\text{For any well-defined algebraic fraction}\;\;\frac ab\;,\;\;\text{we have that}\;\frac ab=0\iff a=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint!. Do you mean this is possible here: **4X² ÷ (1-x²) * (1-x²) = 0 * (1-x²)**

Comment: I'm not a mathematic pro, any topic should I read about before doing this?

Comment: @Naveen, this is basic high school stuff, so I suppose any decent high school algebra book will deal with fractions...

Comment: Not quite $\frac{4X^2}{\sqrt{1-X^2}} = 0 \Rightarrow 4X^2 = 0 \cdot \sqrt{1-X^2} = 0$ So $4X^2 = 0 \Rightarrow X = 0.$

Comment: @DonAntonio $\dfrac{x}{x^2-x}$ has no zeroes.

Comment: I know, @MichaelHoppe...and that's why I mentioned the **"well defined"** thingy: your example is well defined for $\;x\neq 0,1\;$ and thus can be zero (or whatever) only in its definition domain.

Comment: Who/what are you addressing in your comment, @WarrenHill ? It's a good idea to mention this in a thread where several users are participating.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Do you think that I should  assume
**either (4X²) = 0 or (1/1-x²) = 0** I Still can't get a particular value for x. Can you help please?

Comment: I don't get you, @Naveen: if $\;\frac{4x^2}{1-x^2}=0\;$ then $\;4x^2=0\iff x=0\;$ , by the above...what's unclear here?

Comment: @DonAntonio: OMG! I'm not familiar with ⟺ sign. From the last comment, did you mean this? : if **4X²/(1-x²) = 0** then **4X²** must be **0** as well as **x**? Sorry for these dumb questions.. I'm a biology guy..

Comment: @Naveen, yes: I meant that...and a biology (or physics, or chemistry, or any other natural science's) guy *must* know basic mathematics. Never mind, you have though to learn some stuff.